# Symbol non found when run rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just installed Ruby on Rails via rvm on a mac running mountain lion.
When i run the server i got this error , what it's means?

```
   **********:DII ****$ rails server
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_utf8_encoding
  Referenced from: /Users/*******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@DII/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_utf8_encoding
  Referenced from: /Users/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@DII/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

---

The problem was that before upgrading ruby this project was running under ruby 1.8.7 and i get this problem. It was only a test project so i created a new one from zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you're trying to run ruby 1.8.7 with gems that were compiled for ruby 1.9.3 - something has got its knickers in a twist

I'd try re-installing the gems into a clean gemset and make sure you are using the ruby version that you think you are

Comment: yes it was a problem like this. i restarted the project and all goes fine under 1.9.3 thank you so much anyway :) I think that some library was bounded on an older version and trying to install i was getting this error!